# Folder Options has "-ON" and "-OFF" appended to all options

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, accessibility

On one of our user's computers (on Windows 7, Folder Options -> View), I see things like

```
"Don't show hidden, files, folders or drives-ON" (which is selected)
"Show hidden files, folders, and drives-OFF"
```

Usually I would see just

```
"Don't show hidden, files, folders or drives" (which is selected)
"Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
```

All options in View all have "-ON" or "-OFF" appended.  I've never seen this before, but a few other people on the web seem to have this.  All the Google-Fu I try only gives me directions on how to find Folder Options and enable specific items.

I have looked under Ease of Access Center because it smacks of this, but I can't find an option for this there.  I have tried the "Restore Defaults" button in the Folder Options -> View, but this doesn't help either.

Does anywhere know where this option comes from and/or how it can be changed?

I'm a little extra concerned because I just dealt with a virus on this machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Does anywhere know where this option comes from and/or how it can be changed?

These options appear when you have the [Magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7) turned on.

To remove them turn off the Magnifier:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > "Control Panel" > "All Control Panel Items" > "Ease of Access Center" > "Make the computer easier to see".
- Uncheck "Turn on Magnifier".
- Click "OK".
- You may have to close and reopen the Explorer "Folder Options" dialog to see the changes.

[image]

Comment: Never would have guessed it came from that.  Of course, my user had magnifier hidden, although it was on.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Searching for "windows 7 folder options append  with on or off" gave me the answer ;)